# Having same params management of link_to with button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my front-end I created a card with using the `link_to` helper and now I need to add another `link_to` in this card.
(A card entirely clickable with a button inside which lead to another action)
But anchor element cannot be nested so I changed my first `link_to xx_path` with a `button_to xx_path, method: :get` but I want to manage the params same with my link_to.
Here is what I tried

```rb
#My initial link_to I tried to change
link_to article_path(@article, top: params[:top], current_page: params[:page]) do ...

#This one doesn't pass any params 
button_to aritcle_path(@article, top: params[:top], current_page: params[:page]), method: :get do ...

#This one send me every params even if they are nil which then lead to an ugly url like:
#localhost:3000/article/1?top=&current_page=
button_to aritcle_path(@article), params: { top: params[:top], current_page: params[:page] }, method: :get do ...
```

I guess maybe `button_to` is not the solution to my problem but I don't know how to do otherwise.

Comment: `button_to` is a form and `link_to` is an anchor. For `button_to` you have to pass `params` for them to be params. Not sure I understand the `nil` concern as the `link_to` will do the same but you can `compact` a Hash to remove the `nil`s if you want.

Comment: I thought they do the same too but if I do this `article_path(@article, top: nil, current_page: nil)` my controller will not receive any of this params while with a button_to using `params: { top: nil, current_page: nil }` the same controller will receive params { top: "", current_page: "" } as a params which create a redirection to an url with empty visible option `localhost:3000/article/1?top=&current_page=`. I honestly don't know why it act like that. Thank you for the `compact` suggestion that I will use if I don't find a better solution.

Comment: Neither of these options will produce valid HTML since you cannot nest forms in a link either. And while I get the concept of I want a big area that when I click anywhere except the button inside will lead to X and if I click the button it will lead to Y its not how HTML or good accessibility design works. You can do it with JavaScript or some CSS trickery if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need or want to use `button_to` when sending `GET` requests. `button_to` is for sending `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` requests.

It doesn't do anything in that case that cannot be done with a simple anchor element. While you do occasionally use forms for GET requests that's because you want to use inputs.

Instead just pass a compacted hash to the path helper:

```
link_to article_path(
  @article, 
  **{ top: params[:top], current_page: params[:page] }.compact_blank
) do ...
```

Using the double splat (**) to convert the hash to keywords is optional as the method doesn't actually use keyword arguments. But it will prevent the code from breaking in the future if that changes.

### However.

Nesting a form inside a link is just as invalid as a link. [The permitted contents are](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> Transparent, except that no descendant may be interactive content or an a element, and no descendant may have a specified tabindex attribute.

So while this might solve the immediate problem you still need to rethink your whole approach.